# JSF and XHTML files - browser receives full source code, with jsf elements not processed by glassfish

Tags: jsf, netbeans, glassfish, java-ee-6, facelets

Ok, so the problem is - I've created a new EJB project in netbeans. I've created a new .xhtml file in web application that I've mapped in web.xml as the project's welcome-file.

Content of `index.xhtml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">


    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
            <p>test1</p>
           <h:outputText value="test2"/>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

So I run the project. A new page in my browser (Firefox 18) opens, and all I see is... Nothing else except 'test1'. So I right-click on the page, 'see page source', and I see exactly what has been written in the index.xhtml. It's like glassfish throws the page back at me explicitly as I've written it.

There are no errors thrown in glassfish logs. All clear there.

contents of `web.xml` look like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup> 1 </load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
   <welcome-file-list>  
        <welcome-file>/index.xhtml</welcome-file>  
    </welcome-file-list>  

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
```

So, please, could anybody tell me, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Because it's not a web project. Create a new web project, deploy it, then compare the two package structures

Comment: I have no idea what kind of project structures Netbeans produces, but I'll for simplicitly assume that you're indeed putting JSF artifacts in the WAR part of a standard EAR/EJB/WAR project. In that case, have you read the server logs for any errors/warnings?

Comment: @Ian Traum - What happens if you bypass the welcome mechanism and go directly to `host:port/context/index.xhtml`?

Comment: @perissf : Goddamnit, I don't know why I wrote EJB, I've meant EAR, and yes, I've done what I've written in WAR part of my application. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: @BalusC : Absolutely no errors.

Comment: @McDowell : Nothing changes.

Comment: I had that once too... I can't really remember what the reason was, but I think that the faces servlet is just not registered by glassfish out of some strange reasons. I am not sure how I fixed that problem back then, I think I created a new project and adapted the files of the new project step by step ensuring that it still works with glassfish and finally got something working. Maybe try something like that too.